# a counter in constructor

Tags: c++

how to put a counter in constructor??

Comment: You close questions too fast.  not friendly and not fair.

Comment: @lital: Closing as "not a real question" just means that there isn't enough information provided to answer the question as it's written. The asker is free (and encouraged) to edit their question to include additional clarification information, and then their question can be re-opened. The reason to close it early is so that you don't accumulate a bunch of different and wrong answers, just because the question was poorly written to begin with. Fixing the question also improves the quality of the answers.

Comment: So the wording "not a real question" should be changed, because it is offensive when someone asks a real question and gets this remark.

Comment: @lital: Why is it offensive? I don't see anything blatantly offensive about the wording .The description underneath explains what it means. In particular, the last part implies what my comment above says, that the problem lies with its *current form* and it can be modified so that it *can* be answered. Also, I'd be remiss if I didn't refer to you the [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) site, where issues like this can be better discussed.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to count the number of created objects, you can use a static (class) variable

```
class CountingClass {
private:
  static int count;
public:
  CountingClass() {
    ++CountingClass::count;
  }
};
```